# Not able to add another JSON object while checking this API in Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, postman

I was trying to put another JSON object through Postman in an API that I have built.

It was a tutorial from Mosh Hamedani's [YT channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKd0Rpw7O48&t=3s&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithMosh)  where he was teaching about how to make a API using Node.js, Express and Postman.

Throughout the video everything he showed worked pretty good, but only in this section this code is not able to take a POST request in Postman.

As soon as I select Body > Raw and send the request after pasting the localhost URL in postman, it is coming up with an error.

The whole thing is mentioned underneath.

This is the code for the API

```
`const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const courses = [
    { id: 1, name: 'courses1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'courses2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'courses3'},
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/courses', (req,res) => {
    res.send(courses);
});

app.post('/api/course', (req,res) => {
    const course = {
        id: course.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});

app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req,res) => {
    const course = courses.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.params.id));
    if (!course) res.status(404).send('the course with the given ID was not found.');
    res.send(course);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));`
```

Trying to add another JSON object by using this code in postman

```
    `{
    "name": "courses"
}
`
```

And postman terminal is returning this error:

```
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/courses</pre>
</body>
</html>`
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: you defined `/api/course`  and `/api/courses/:id`  but you try to execute request for address  `/api/courses` which do not exists (it requires ID parameter) which (with `:id`) is mandatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman show 'Cannot POST /api/courses', meanwhile in your code, you define to use GET on 'api/courses'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /api/courses</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

So, you can check further about that

```
// this is only GET
app.get('/api/courses', (req,res) => {
    res.send(courses);
});

// this is use /api/course, not /api/courses
app.post('/api/course', (req,res) => {
    const course = {
        id: course.length + 1,
        name: req.body.name
    };
    courses.push(course);
    res.send(course);
});
```